# Wikitude SDK - ignoring license key on first run

Tags: objective-c, ios, wikitude

I am using the tutorial example code provided by the wikitude SDK and adapting it to my needs. However when I pass a valid license key to the ARchitect browser (this happens in the viewDidAppear method of the view controller) via

```
NSString * wkKey = @"50m3r4nd0m51gn5";
[self.architectView initializeWithKey:<myKey> motionManager:nil];
```

and build and run the application on my development device (iPhone 4) from XCode I still get the beta watermarks all behind the augmented reality view as if I didn't provide any license key. The license key however is available when I inspect the object in the debugger, it just seems to be ignored by the ARchitect View initializer.

When I close the app on the device with the home button, and open it again on the device, the license key obviously gets recognized this time and the beta watermarks are gone.

What I tried:

- putting the initializer in the vieWillAppear method - no change
- providing the key directly, without the variable - no change

Does anyone have a clue if this is an issue with the SDK or could it be a timing issue from where I call it in my code?
Since I can't find much about wikitude and especially anything about my problem any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I still used the 1.0.3 release of the wikitude sdk while in the meantime v1.1.1 was released - after an upgrade, the "beta" watermarks and/or the wikitude logo were not displayed anymore..

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that the license key you're using is provided by Wikitude and does not contain any whitespaces. The key displayed '50m3r4nd0m51gn5' doesn't seem to be correct. Please have a look at the SimpleARBrowser/WTSecondViewController.m/viewWillAppear. You will get a valid license key when registering your application with Wikitude under: http://www.wikitude.com/store

To verify existing keys please contact sales[at]wikitude.com

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

Comment: thanks for your reply, of course the "somerandomsigns" key is only an example, I wasn't going to post my real key which I already got from registering my application :) but I will check again for some whitespaces..

Comment: hmm, I couldn't find any whitespaces in the key, hopefully the support can help..

Comment: ok, so I had the wrong key, it was for another App..now that I have the correct one however the problem is still not solved..